# How can I execute Perl code specified on the command line?

Tags: perl

I want something like..

#### all_objects.pl

```
my $sub = $ARGV[1];
...

@objs = get_all_objects();
for my $obj (@objs) {
    // invoke subroutine $sub with param as $obj.   
}
```

now if I say

```
all_objects.pl "print 'x '" 

all_objects.pl "print '$_ '"
```

I should get

```
obj1 obj2 obj3 ...
```

i.e. the command line arg act as a subroutine in some way. Can this be achieved?

Comment: This script will finally shoot your leg off, remember my words.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? We might be able to suggest a better way if we know what the point is.

Comment: baskin wants to do some debugging stuff. See comments to Ether's post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval ""` is bad. Use something like the following, if it fulfills your needs:

```
my ($sub) = @ARGV;

my %prepared = (
    print => sub { print "$_[0]\n" },
    woof  => sub { $_[0]->woof },
    meow  => sub { $_[0]->meow },
);

@objs = get_all_objects();
for my $obj (@objs) {
    $prepared{$sub}->($obj);   
}
```

**Update:**  For debugging purposes, Perl has a debugger: [`perldoc perldebug`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)

Answer (score 1):

Eval is evil unless you really know what you're doing (think of it as an unshielded thermonuclear nuke -- sure you could handle one if you had to, and it might even save the world, but you'd be better off leaving it as a last resort, and let the nuclear physicists deal with it.)

You could put your `all_objects.pl` code into a module, and then use the module on the command line:

put this into AllObjects.pm:

```
package AllObjects;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_all_objects
{
    # code here...
}
1;
```

Now on the command line:

```
perl -I. -MAllObjects -wle'for my $obj (AllObjects::get_all_objects()) { print "object is $obj" }'
```

However, it's not really clear what you are trying to achieve with the overall design.

You can read more about perl command-line invokation at [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), and making modules at p[erldoc perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) (as well as many posts here on Stack Overflow).

Comment: HI Ether, the intention is to avoid repeating some debugging code for self-use, nothing production quality certainly.

Comment: what repeat of debugging code are you really avoiding with this technique?

Comment: *String* `eval` may be an unshielded nuke, but *block* `eval` is just Perl's way of spelling `try`.  Not all `eval`s are evil.  (But OP was looking for string `eval`, so carry on...)